# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table paths has no column named path (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO paths(path) VALUES (?)

Tags: android, sqlite

So I've looked around on Stackoverflow and all the issues related to this seem to be down to syntax error, but I'm fairly certain my syntax is correct

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_DB_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PATHS + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " paths"+ ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_TABLE);
}

public void addPath(FilePath filePath) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, filePath.getFilePath1());
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_PATHS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

So I have the onCreate and the addPath methods.

```
db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

Then I have in my activity in the onCreate method this. Does this create the database automatically once this is called, I'm a little confused on how this works. I don't think I have it right. Any guidance on the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: The SQLiteException shows that 'path' does not exists, while you create a column named 'paths' (notice the s)

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table paths has no column named paths (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO paths(paths) VALUES (?)
I've changed it now and I get this. So there is stil no 'paths' after changing the KEY_NAME to add an s

Comment: if you edited your create query after creating a table then you have to uninstall your app and install again or use alter table commands

Comment: Yeah I've just updated my table and it's working now. Thanks!